# DATAFRAME (Exception has occurred: ProgrammingError (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'dict')

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I am having a "Exception has occurred: ProgrammingError (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'dict'" error message while using sqlalchemy and psycopg to inject a dataframe to a postgres database

I am writing a script to pull  inject a kobo dataFrame into a local postgres database. Everything seems to be working except the injection. It gives me an error message:

Exception has occurred: ProgrammingError (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'dict'

```
This is my code below. Please assist.


import psycopg2
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.types import String
import pykobo



# establish connections
conn_string = 'postgresql://postgres:openppp@localhost:5432/wpp_appeals'

db = create_engine(conn_string)
conn = db.connect()



URL_KOBO_API = "https://kf.kobotoolbox.org/api/v2"
MYTOKEN = "1e83cdede6c48a19ef210e417d6ca61b076db175"
km = pykobo.Manager(url_api=URL_KOBO_API, token=MYTOKEN)

uid = 'aQCxZ9BVrHe33pLMdtx3gV'
my_form = km.get_form(uid)

    
my_form.fetch_data()  
df1 = my_form.data


df1.to_sql('appeals', con=conn, if_exists='append', index=False, dtype={
    'deviceid':sqlalchemy.String(),
    'TimeStartRecorded':sqlalchemy.VARCHAR(),
    'TimeEndRecorded':sqlalchemy.VARCHAR(),
    'today':sqlalchemy.VARCHAR(),
    'Appeals_Feedback':sqlalchemy.VARCHAR(),
    'Location':sqlalchemy.VARCHAR(),
    'gps_location':sqlalchemy.VARCHAR(),
    '_gps_location_latitude':sqlalchemy.VARCHAR(),
    '_gps_location_longitude':sqlalchemy.VARCHAR(),
    '_gps_location_altitude':sqlalchemy.VARCHAR(),
    '_gps_location_precision':sqlalchemy.VARCHAR(),
    'householdID':sqlalchemy.VARCHAR(),
    'hhNumber':sqlalchemy.VARCHAR(),
    'confirm1':sqlalchemy.VARCHAR(),
    'focalPointName':sqlalchemy.VARCHAR(),
    'validz':sqlalchemy.VARCHAR(),
    '_id':sqlalchemy.VARCHAR(),
    '_uuid':sqlalchemy.VARCHAR(),
    '_submission_time':sqlalchemy.VARCHAR(),
    '_validation_status':sqlalchemy.VARCHAR(),
    '_notes':sqlalchemy.VARCHAR(),
    '_status':sqlalchemy.VARCHAR(),
    '_submitted_by':sqlalchemy.VARCHAR(),
    '_tags':sqlalchemy.VARCHAR(),
    '_index':sqlalchemy.VARCHAR()})

conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string
                        )

conn.autocommit = True
                     


#conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: To your question add/answer the following: 1) Why is `conn` defined twice? 2) The complete trace back for the error.

Comment: It seems that one of your Dataframe columns content is a dictionary and not a string as expected. If I have to guess I would take a look at the content of your '_tags' column. Could you please provide a short example of yours Dataframe's content.